# I always get warning when I add text or button in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, warnings, android-button

I am a new Android Developer and I downloaded and installed Eclipse using the xdatv steps on *How to Build an Android App Part 1: Setting up Eclipse and Android SDK*

Here is how I installed it:

1. First I download the SDK.  (It contains the SDK and Eclipse in the same .rar file.)
2. I extracted the files(SDK and Eclipse) in one folder.
3. I opened Eclipse and added the browsed folder where I extracted the SDK and Eclipse files as the Workspace.
4. And I opened the SDK to download the SDK version I chose Android 2.3.3 (API 10).
5. I opened Eclipse and went to the Help category and I chose Install New software. I added that link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and checked the Developer tool and NDK Plugin, then I downloaded them.

And before I start to create an Android app, I check in the Workspace setting if the SDK location is correct in the folder where sdk and eclipse in/sdk folder.

Finally when I started to create an app, I tried to add a button or text, but I always get a warning when I add a button `[I8N]Hardcoded string "button", should use @string resource` and I got the same warning on the text.

I searched for answer for my problem and I found I did the same thing that they did (I added `@string/` on this code `android:text="@string/button" />` on the button and also in the text code).

And I added on `strings.xml` these codes:

```
<string name="button">Button</string>
<string name="Testtext">Test text</string>
```

The warning disappeared but there is something annoying me -- it always shows `@string` in the button and the text in the graphical layout:

> [image: http://i39.tinypic.com/2w583mw.jpg]

I think that it must always be that when I add text or a button it automatically adds the `@string` and in the `strings.xml` adds the these codes `<string name="my_string">Your Text!</string>`.  I just want know what the wrong thing that I did to get this warning and why it doesn't add these codes automatically in the .xml files and how to fix that.
Thanks

Comment: Please, put yout xml Button and TextView here and the strings.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that it must always be that when I add text or a button it
>   automatically adds the @string and in the strings.xml adds the these
>   codes Your Text!

NO (atleast in Eclipse thats not the case)

> why it doesn't add these codes automatically in the .xml files

In Eclipse no automatic addition of code in strings.xml is done. You have to add them manually.

**As far as your warning is Graphical Layout is concerned :-**

You have correctly done mapping of those srings in strings.xml. Just follow the below steps.

- make sure ids are exact as mentioned in strings.xml
- Save-all.
- Select your project and click <kbd>F5</kbd> to Refreash.
- Clean and build your project.

Your `Couldn't resolve resourses ---` error will be gone..

Check on emulator or a real devices.